# Is the proposition $P$ equivalent to the axiom of regularity

Tags: set-theory, propositional-calculus

My understanding of Axiomatic Set theory is not too deep so apologies if its not very clear. This question is assuming we are considering ZFC.

## Background to question

Consider the proposition $P$. For sets $x,y$ we say define recursively $
P(x,y)$ is true $ \iff (x \in y)\lor (\exists a \in y (P(x,a)))$

Alternatively $P(x,y)$ is true if $x\in y$ or $\exists$ z at the end of a terminating chain of inclusions of $y$ such that $x \in z$.

It seems intuitively true to me that $P(x,x)\to\bot$ but I'm not sure how to formalize it.

Assuming $P(x,x)$ to be true we see that evidentially $x\not \in x$ so we must have that $\exists$ some $z \in a \in b \in \cdots\in x$ such that $x \in z$. But this just means you can follow a chain of inclusions of x and find x in itself again.

It seems analogous to a case of sets $(a \in b) \land (b\in a)$ but two such sets can never exist as it contradicts the axiom of regularity.

## Question

First off how do I properly formalize this proof? And is the proposition P equivalent to the axiom of regularity (as it seems to only be decided by that)?

Comment: How do you want to define $P$ recursively if you don't assume regularity in the first place? The whole point of regularity is that you can perform recursion/induction on sets. Also, what is $P(x,y) \rightarrow \top$ even supposed to say? $\top$ is always true, so the implication is also always true.

Comment: Well i meant to say P(x,y) is true iff.. the rest of the conditions edited to match

Comment: It seems that $P(x, y) \iff x\in \operatorname{TC}(y)$ — that is, $x$ is a member of the transitive closure of $y$, where $\operatorname{TC}(y) :=  y \cup (\bigcup y) \cup (\bigcup\bigcup y)\, \cup ...$